# Old Mensa Norway Question 32 - lines above a square

Tags: pattern, visual, progressive-matrix

[image]

The answer is the option in the spoiler, but I can't quite figure out why.

> D (bottom left)

Source: This question was on the [Mensa Norway IQ Test](https://test.mensa.no), but now is on the [Mensa Finland IQ Test](https://www.mensa.fi/iq/index_2.html).

Comment: Has a useful answer been given? If so, please don't forget to $\color{green}{\checkmark \small\text{Accept}}$ it :)

Answer (score 8):

I'm not a fan of these types of puzzles but I think the reasoning is as follows

> Rotate the central diamond image $45^o$ anti-clockwise so that their edges are now horizontal and vertical.
>  Then, in each row, if we take the XOR value of the edges surrounding the left square with the edges surrounding the middle square, we obtain the edges surrounding the right square.
>  In particular, on the bottom row, the left square has got an edge on its right-hand side and the middle square will have edges on its top and left. The result of taking the XOR of these edge values is a square with edges on its top, left and right. This is the image in the bottom left of the possible answers.

Comment: I'm just typing the answer :P

Answer (score 0):

The answer may be:

> [image: Box with line at top]

Reasoning:

> In the first two examples, the state of the bottom line is the same between the shaded box at left and the unshaded box at right. the middle symbol is an arrow, pointing to a direction. In the middle symbol, the two exterior lines can be interpreted as an arrow, which points the direction in which the other exterior line should move. In the final example, the lack of bottom line under the shaded square indicates we should not have a bottom line, and the arrow in the middle square points up, indicating there should be a top line. This corresponds to the figure above.

Comment: What do you mean by C?

Comment: Howdy, and welcome to PSE! I've taken the liberty of expanding and cleaning up your post, but I think you applied some interesting logic to the problem. For your knowledge, the best received answers on PSE are those that clearly (and ideally cleverly) explain the logic behind them...I hope this example provides some ideas on how you can get a better reception in the future!